# Finding the ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals, factoring

> Determine all the ideals, prime ideals, and maximal ideals of $\mathbb{R}[x]/I$ where $I$ is the ideal generated by $(x^2+1)(x-2)^2$.

I am currently doing some reading on ideals (see http://www.math.niu.edu/~beachy/aaol/rings.html#ideals), and I must say I am somewhat confused. The author describes what ideals are, but does not provide examples as to how to determine these in situations like the one above? **What specific steps am I supposed to take to answer questions of the type which is shown above?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhere in your notes you should find a result that links  ideals of a domain $R$ containing some ideal $I$,  to those of $R/I$.

Then you are left with the task of determining the ideals that contain $I$. To do this recall that you are working in a PID where each ideal is thus generated by a single element and inclusion of ideals is linked to divisibility of generating elements.

Comment: As I just checked: "somewhere" is "Prop 5.3.7.b"

Comment: Forgive me for my slowness but I want to be absolutely clear that I get the point correctly. The nonzero ideals of $\mathbb{R}[x]$ are all principal, of the form $\langle f(x) \rangle$, where $f(x)$ is any polynomial of minimal degree in the ideal. I now wonder what the minimal degree of the polynomial is in this case; is it $(x^2+1)$?

Comment: Yes all ideals are of this form. For your ideal $I$ the polynomial is just the one that you have in the question; it is stated $I$ is the ideal generated by that polynomial. By contrast the ideal generated by $x^2 + 1 $ is larger than $I$ and is one of the ideals you will need to consider, along with the polynomials generated by all the other divisors of $(x^2+1)(x-2)^2$

Comment: If $I$ had been the ideal generated **only **by $(x-2)^2$ then there would have been only one proper ideal, $x-2$. Correct? Now, when we consider the polynomial $(x^2+1)(x-2)^2$ we observe that its divisors are$x-i,x+i$ and $x-2$. If I understand you correctly, I am supposed to consider these and the polynomials they generated. As long as we are dealing with $\mathbb{R}[x]$, $x \pm i$ cannot be ideals, and so we have $x-2,(x-2)^2$ and $x^2+1$

Comment: The first claim is correct. The second is almost correct. You are correct to excude the factors containing complex numbers; a more direct argument is that $(x-i)$ is not a divisor of $X^2+1$ in the real polynomial ring, or put differently the polynomial is irredcuible over the reals.  But be careful to consider all divisors; there is also $(x-2)(x^2+1)$.

Comment: Let me then try to summaries what I have learned: The ideals when $\mathbb{R}[x]$ are $x-2,(x-2)^2,x^2+1$, and $(x^2+1)(x-2)$; the prime ideals are $x-2$ and $x^2+1$; how about the maximal?

Comment: Yes this is a list of all proper ideals properly containing $I$, or rather their generating elements to be precise. The ring is a PID, so  non-zero prime ideal is the same as maximal ideal.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. As a finale may I just ask if these are the ideals when we consider the case $\mathbb{C}[x]$? $x-i,x+i,x^2+1,x-2,(x-2)^2,(x-i)(x-2),(x-i)(x-2)^2,(x+i)(x-2),(x+i)(x-2)^2,$ and $(x^2+1)(x-2)$

Comment: You are welcome. Yes this are all the proper divisors in this case.